# How can i sum the time stamps of one day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timedelta

I am using Pandas.

I have the following dataset:
[dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CFkW.png)

This is one-year data containing details of trade exchanges happening per day.
i want to sum the total minutes of one day for which trade is happening.
For e.g if on `2009-04-01`, trade starts at `9:30:50` and ends at `15:45:10`, then total minutes are:

> [(15-9)*60+(30+45]+(50+10)/60)

I am unable to do this by resampling function.

The dates are in DateTimeIndex format.
I'm new to Pandas.

Comment: Please post your data as text, not image - try to create a [mre] from it (doesn't even have to be your *real* data). E.g. on the image, it seems your column TIME is dtype timedelta, not time, as your question suggests. What is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better use `datetime` for this matter.

Since you have the starttime and endtime as string in the snapshot. You could do this:

```
import datetime

starttime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2009-04-01 9:30:50', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
endtime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2009-04-01 15:45:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
((endtime - starttime).seconds) / 60
```

Comment: i think the method you told is only for two specific times. How can i apply this method for a Series? i have a column of timestamps

Comment: You could use `groupby` as MrFuppes said. Or you could iterate all index and find the starttime and endtime for each day. You'd better attach more samples in format of code.

Answer (score 1):

you can groupby the date and use [numpy's ptp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) to get the max-to-min difference of the timedeltas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# from the question I assume your df looks like
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ["2020-04-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-02"],
                   'TIME': ["9:30:50", "15:45:10", "8:30:50", "15:45:10"]})

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])

totalTimes = df.groupby('DATE')['TIME'].agg(np.ptp)
# DATE
# 2020-04-01   0 days 06:14:20
# 2020-04-02   0 days 07:14:20
# Name: TIME, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want e.g. the total minutes, you can use the `.total_seconds()` to calculate them, e.g.

```
totalTimes.loc['2020-04-01'].total_seconds()/60
# 374.3333333333333
```